# How to check if a string matches multiple strings and return value based on match

Tags: c#

Apologizes if the title doesn't make much sense, English isn't my native language.

What I am trying to do:
1. I have a list of strings
2. I want to check each of those strings against another list of strings
3. Depending which string they contain, the output will be different

In code, it looks like this:

```
public static Hashtable Matches = new Hashtable
{
    {"first_match", "One"},
    {"second_match", "Two"},
    {"third_match", "Three"},
    {"fourth_match", "Four!"},
    {"fifth_match", "Five"}
};
```

Now, I have a list of strings like this:

```
001_first_match
010_second_match
011_third_match
```

And I want to check if each string in the list exists in the hashtable (or maybe other data type appropriate for this situation, suggestions appreciated) and based on that, to take the value for the key.

For example: `001_first_match` is in the hashtable with `first_match` key. If found, then I want to take the `One` value of it and use it.

I can't use `ContainsKey` because the list of strings isn't 100% exact as the keys. The key is contained within the string, but there's extra data in the string.

I hope it's not too confusing what I want to do.

Comment: Wouldn't replace be better here? Just replace in a string every key with it's value (you need to run a loop through HashMap keys

Comment: `Mathes.ContainsKey("001_first_match".Substring(4))`?

Comment: @SergeyProsin If I understood correct, you are saying to loop through all keys, then replace their values and then solve my problem? If so, how can I update the keys? Aren't they non-replaceable ?

Comment: @tym32167 That might work for the case I shown, but in reality the length could be more than 4 unfortunately.

Comment: if you have random changes in string, how you plan to match them? I mean, imagine that in your hashtable there are keys `['key', 'key2']` and you have string `key25` - so both of keys matched. How you will resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication58
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] inputs = { "001_first_match", "010_second_match", "011_third_match" };

            foreach (string input in inputs)
            {
                var results = Matches.Keys.Cast<string>().Where(x => input.Contains(x)).FirstOrDefault();
                Console.WriteLine("Input '{0}' found in HashTable : {1}", input,  (results == null) ? "False" : "True, key = '" + results + "', Value = '" + Matches[results] + "'");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
        public static Hashtable Matches = new Hashtable
        {
            {"first_match", "One"},
            {"second_match", "Two"},
            {"third_match", "Three"},
            {"fourth_match", "Four!"},
            {"fifth_match", "Five"}
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: How would I get the value of the key with this method, rather than `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq to do this by enumerating over the hashtable, casting each item to `DictionaryEntry`, and seeing if any element of the list of strings contains the key from the hashtable:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var Matches = new Hashtable
            {
                {"first_match", "One"},
                {"second_match", "Two"},
                {"third_match", "Three"},
                {"fourth_match", "Four!"},
                {"fifth_match", "Five"}
            };

            var Targets = new List<string>
            {
                "001_first_match",
                "010_second_match",
                "011_third_match"
            };

            var matches =
                Matches.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                .Where(x => Targets.Any(s => s.Contains((string)x.Key)))
                .Select(v => v.Value);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", matches)); // Outputs "Three", "One" and "Two".
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class StringMatch
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> Matches = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "first_match", "One" },
            { "second_match", "Two" },
            { "third_match", "Three" },
            { "fourth_match", "Four!" },
            { "fifth_match", "Five" }
        };

        public List<string> Strings = new List<string>
        {
            "001_first_match",
            "010_second_match",
            "011_third_match"
        };

        [Test]
        public void FindMatches()
        {
            foreach (var item in Strings)
            {
                foreach (var match in Matches)
                {
                    if (item.Contains(match.Key))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can do this by two dimensional array hope it can help you.

```
public string test() 
        {
            string result="";
            string[,] Hashtable = new string[2,2]
{
    {"first_match", "One"},
    {"second_match", "Two"},

};
            string match = "001_first_match";

            for (int i = 0; i < Hashtable.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
               string test1=  Hashtable[i, 0];
               if (match.Contains(test1)) { result = Hashtable[i, 1]; }

            }
            return result;
        }
```